# Java code to create encrypted SAML Assertion

Tags: java, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0, opensaml

How to create an encrypted saml2.0 assertion in java?

Downloaded sample project from http://www.capcourse.com/Library/OpenSAML/index.html

I am new to this .. can someone please provide the steps or links to do so..

Comment: What existing libraries have you investigated/searched?

Comment: I have downloaded a sample project from http://www.capcourse.com/Library/OpenSAML/index.html ...

Comment: Have you tried opensaml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check [this](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OpenSAML/OSTwoUserManual) for general info

[Here](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OpenSAML/OSTwoUserManJavaXMLEncryption) is an encryption and decryption sample. DON'T FORGET to BOOTSTRAP OpenSAML2 before using it's functions it's one of most common mistakes.

Comment: The two links are not reachable